# Tracking AppView events in GA via Google Tag Manager from iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get GA **Screens** working via Google Tag Manager on iOS. I've configured GTM Tag with the tracking type **App View** and I am able to see that events are coming but screen name is always **(not set)**

[image: GA view]

I was trying to set different variables/parameters in GTM but haven't succeeded so far. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was very complicated and absolutly not documented from google side. You have to configure your tag as App View and add field &cd and set it's value to your screen name. It can be tracked then in real time.
[image: gtm panel configuration]

Look here for some more context: [google documentation for google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd)

Comment: That's the twist!!! Looks like in the last version of Tag Manager they replace automatically &cd to screenName so the following code works for me now 
[dataLayer push:@{@"event": @"openScreen", @"screenName": screenName}];

Comment: Indeed. Just noticed that. So it's screenName then now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code I use.

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

You should probably use this though:

```
NSString *screenName = /* YOUR SCREEN NAME HERE */
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:screenName];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

Comment: Looks like you're using google analytics directly and I need to use it via google tag manager.

Answer (score -2):

Code:

```
[dataLayer push:@{@"event": @"screenView",@"screenName":name}]
```

[image]